# Strange session issue in PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm having a strange issue with sessions in PHP. Basically, when a user submits a contact form, the processing script sets a session on completion ( `$_SESSION['action']='sent';` ). The user is then sent back to the page they sent the form from and a message is displayed using the following code:

```
$action = $_SESSION['action'];

if ( $action == 'sent' )
{
echo '<p>Thank you for contacting us, we will be in touch with you ASAP.</p>';
unset($_SESSION['action']);
}
```

The session is unset so if they refresh the page or navigate away and come back the message won't be displaying any more.

Basically the problem is that when the session is unset it seems to unset it from the very beginning of the script so that the message doesn't display. The `if` statement is obviously running as the session is being unset, but the message isn't displaying.

I've used this exact same script many times before and it works absolutely perfectly on other sites (on the same server, with all the same settings).

Any help/advice would be appreciated!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code, it's something else. Do you have any 301/302/meta/js redirects which could be causing the code to execute without displaying? I used to use a similar message-passing mechanism and this was what always tripped me up.

Comment: The only redirect involved in this process is the one that sends the user from the contact script back to the page. It's done using the code 'header("location:".$page_url);'. The page URL variable is set depending on which page the form is submitted from, as it is on multiple pages on the site.

Comment: It's nothing silly like a session_write_close() somewhere previously in the script?

Comment: Nope, it's quite a small site and this is actually the only part of it that deals with sessions. I've thoroughly looked through the code and there is nothing that should stop this working. Could it be to do with my php settings or something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you initialized a session?
`session_start();` before output something in browser?

Comment: Yes I am. The message displays if I remove the unset($_SESSION['action']); from the code. It's unsetting it which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a session_destroy(); instead of unset($_SESSION);
Could you give us the part where you start the session and where you set the "action" to "sent"?

Comment: session_destory(); has the same effect, I'm afraid. The session is set in the form processing script with $_SESSION['action']='sent'; and all the files involved have session_start(); as their first lines.

Comment: Try this: if ( $action == 'sent' ){echo "I'm here"; ......} 
if it outputs the "I'm here" then you have a serious bug somewhere before the if

Comment: What's the difference between this and my code? Changing what is echoed makes no change. Or have I misinterpreted you?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Tom are you making sure the script that start the session is in the same directory  - eg are the commands accessing the same session 
- could be on under one is under https, and one is under http
OR if One is under /, another is under /dir1, and /dir1 was  run first . The cookie created by the session is for /dir1 and deeper, so the other script can't read it; it sees no session so it starts a new one.

I'm not brill at this sessions stuff but it might be worth a check. - Dad

Comment: Not sure that this would make a difference regardless, but the PHP files are all in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is correct. And since the session is being unset, we know that the statements in the if block are being executed. May be the output is actually being displayed by echo, but is just not shown by the browser (this can happen if your css code is configured so). So, just check the source of the output page and check if the source contains the out put message.

In other way, you can put a javascript alert box in your echo and see if it displays an alert box.

`echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Hi'); </script>";`

This should override any hiding css code.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I'll add that I would prefer isset() in this situation:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['sent'])){
    echo "Successfully submitted form!";
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_regenerate_id();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    exit;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //validate input & process form
    $_SESSION['sent'] = 1;
    header("location:form.php"); // name of this file
    exit;
}
echo "Enter your email<br />
<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='email' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>";
exit;
?>
```